# htaccess get one parameter or two depending of the url PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

First of all: If you have a better title for this question let me know.
Hello , I have a site which loads content using get variable.
Let me explain it to you.

My index php file:

```
<?php

    #check if get parameter page exists 
    #check if file exists
    require $_GET['page] . '.php'; //if it exists require its content    

?>
```

In that way users may go to my site and write urls like these ones below:

```
http://localhost/loremipsum?page=home

http://localhost/loremipsum?page=help
```

But to get a cleaner url I edited my .htaccess file to get urls like these ones:

```
http://localhost/loremipsum/home

http://localhost/loremipsum/help
```

The .htaccess:
    
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*) /loremipsum/?pg=$1 [L]

But I got to a point where I need other parameters, For the next url I would like to have `userpreferences` as the `page` parameter and `something` as the `fav` parameter

A url like this would work:

```
http://localhost/loremipsum/userpreferences&fav=something
```

But the goal is to get a url like this:

```
http://localhost/loremipsum/userpreferences/something
```

The problem is that nothing that I have tried have worked, This is what I thought it should work but it didn't:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/userpreferences/(a-zA-Z0-9)+ /loremipsum/?pg=$1&fav=$2 [L]
```

**UPDATE:**

I know this rule should be applied only if page parameter is equal to userpreferences and I was thinking about doing

```
RewriteRule ^userpreferences/(a-zA-Z0-9)+ /loremipsum/?pg=userpreferences&fav=$1 [L]
```

But it won't work, it seems as userpreferences would not be a string and I get a server error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a rewrite rule like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?parameter=$1 [NC]
```

and then you get :

```
index.php?parameter=param/value/param/value
```

From the Browser you get :

```
http://localhost/parameter/param/value/param/value
```

Inside PHP file you could access your parameter:

```
<?php

$parameter = explode( "/", $_GET['parameter'] );
for($i = 0; $i < count($parameter); $i+=2) {

  echo $parameter[$i] ." has value: ". $parameter[$i+1] ."<br />";

}

?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks man, I didn't know the way I'm rewriting my rule is causing all the parameters in only one get variable, that php code was the key, nothing else had to be modified, It's the easiest way I have found until now. Thank you a lot for your time :)